# Does Ant Move Task create the destination directory if it does not exist?

Tags: ant, move

Does [Ant Move Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) create the destination directory if it does not exist?

Should the `dir/to/move/to` directory structure exist before running the following task?

```
<move file="file.orig" todir="dir/to/move/to"/>
```

Comment: The task will create the directories needed.  It uses the java.io.File class mkdirs() method.

Comment: Thanks! @martinclayton I believe your comment should be an answer.